# Tree visualisation and animation

Tags: graphics, animation, haskell, tree

I'm working with multiple search strategies on trees in Haskell. I want to visualize them and also animate the search I'm doing in it. The best I've found so far is [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) images that I could generate by writing DOT files (like in Land of Lisp) but I doubt that it is the best approach. My trees can get quite big so I don't want to enter the position of each node in my program, I want them to be places correctly automatically.

I've also looked a little bit at [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) but I'm not sure if I can input my data in it.

Also my Tree datatype is very basic : `data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)`.

So in short, I'm looking for a way to get tree visualisation and animation on search strategy in it. I'm not looking necessarily for a Haskell centric solution but it could be great. Also being able to output the images/animation in standard format such as gif would a big plus.

Comment: Graphviz can do the layout for you.  Is that not the kind of layout you want?

Comment: The example at Land of Lisp (http://landoflisp.com/graph-util.lisp) uses `dot` to do the placement rather than putting in node positions manually.

Comment: @Jeremiah : yes I want to kind of placement. But is there some way to animate it?

Comment: Just create multiple frames with different highlighting/colors or actual visual animation in a GUI?

Comment: Have you looked at UbiGraph? http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/  There is even impressive presentation for random binary tree: http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Demos/random_binary_tree.html  And a binding for Haskell http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum-ubigraph

Comment: Ed'ka : That's new to me. This seems great but is there some cost associated to it? It says the basic version is free.

Comment: @Jeremiah : multiple frames could be ok but I've seen some animation made that way with graphviz and it wasn't very pleasing to the eye : it wasn't smooth at all and the graph was always moving from place to place in the window.

Comment: @afilatun: You can avoid the jumping around by running `dot -Tplain` on your entire tree and parsing the result to get the coordinates, then just using those for all of the images.  You will still get separate frames, though.

Answer (score 3):

I'll expand my comment:
I haven't investigated pricing policy of Ubigraph, but you can download a free version from their site ("basic" one?). Then you can install vacuum-ubigraph package (there seems to be a build failure HackageDB under GHC 7.0, but I've just managed to install it under my 7.0.2 without a problem). Once it's done you can just start `ubigraph_server` and start 'feeding' it with your data structures right from ghci:

```
import System.Vacuum.Ubigraph

data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
data Root a = Root a

tree =
    Root
    (Branch
     (Branch
      (Leaf "A")
      (Leaf "B"))
     (Leaf "C"))
```

Type `view tree` and you'll get something similar to:

[image]

You can zoom in/out and rotate it. Not sure how practical it is (it shows the entire Haskell object graph like it is - note shared `[]`), but there are lots of settings to play with, so you can definitely make it look nicer. Animation seems to be supported as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you go the Ubigraph route you can just use the HUbigraph bindings directly, for example:

```
import Graphics.Ubigraph
import Control.Monad

main = do
  h <- initHubigraph "http://127.0.0.1:20738/RPC2"
  runHubigraph op h

op = do
  clear
  vs <- mapM (const newVertex) [0..400]
  mapM_ (setVAttr (VShape Sphere)) vs
  let bind i = zipWithM (\a b -> newEdge (a,b)) vs (drop i vs ++ take i vs)
  mapM_ bind [1..15]
  return ()
```

I just spent some time playing with this - it's fun but don't try to up the value of 15 to, say, 40 or ubigraph gets very upset (constant motion of the verticies)!