# Interactive Graph and Tree visualization for Desktop Application in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, visualization

I have seen that there are bindings to graphviz, but it appears to just work with the Dot language and so I'm assuming that it would be more appropriate for static visualization. We have more of a dynamic, often updated, interactive need for automatic laying out and working with graphs and trees. Is there an appropriate library for such a thing in Haskell?

I need something that will work on at least both Linux and Windows

Comment: Do you have to do the layout in haskell?  One option would be to use InfoVis (http://thejit.org/) / ProtoVis (http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/).  Both are javascript & run in the browser (so satisfy cross-platform reqs).  Both consume graph description (no layout info, just edges, vertices & properties).  Protovis uses json iirc.  Presume you could serve that up from haskell and have the browser render.  hth.

Comment: No. I added to title that it's for a desktop application. Need to have the interaction level and deployment model of a desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to come the closest I was able to find so far:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graph-rewriting-layout-0.4.4

I also ran across this:
http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-April/060496.html

Answer (score 1):

There are [bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hubigraph) to [ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/), a closed source graph visualization program/library that has a free-ware version available for download.  Ubigraph is interactive, fairly fast, and really damned easy to use given the hubigraph bindings - see an [old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267963/tree-visualisation-and-animation/5295652#5295652) for a code example.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears that doesn't run on Windows so it won't work for me. I've added that constraint to the question.